# Alter the z-index of fixed top bar when using Full Screen Snippets

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, user-interface, user-experience

We need to hide the fixed header for Stack Overflow or send it back when the full screen snippet comes up. Use case, try full screen snippet on this and try to read it:

```html
Hello! Read this in Full Screen.
```

Comment: Maybe not `z-index` but a `margin-top` the size of the header would do it or anything similar. Seems to be `padding-top: 60px;` on the container of the main page.

Comment: @thepio Z Index would be a better option, so as not to disturb the full screen version of snippet.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes that's maybe true if you would like to hide the header all together. Otherwise the top of the snippet would just "float" on top of the header and get mixed up :P I don't know if the header is visible intentionally or not.

Comment: I can't reproduce this bug on either Chromium 58 or Firefox 53, with or without the sticky nav bar. What browser are you using, and could you post a screenshot of what you see?